# how to run a script with gnuplot then exit from gnuplot and continue with the script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Good afternoon dear all

Look i am quite new to linux and gnuplot.
I have a file that gets split into 4 files (that is carried out in gnuplot), then i want to sort my data of each file (i did that using bash). everything works well if i apply the commands separated, however, i saw that an script using #!/bin/bash can be used. therefore, i tried to use it but anything works, it seems that my problem comes from the for loop of the gnuplot command.

Can somone guide on this?.

Probably this question was asked before but i didn't get any result from other answered questions

this is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Gnuplot";
gnuplot -p << EOF
set datafile separator ","
do for [i=0:3] {
    set table 'point-'.i.'.csv'
    set datafile missing "NaN"
    plot 'test.csv' using ($3 != i ? 1/0 : $3):($3 != i ? 1/0 : $5):($3 != i ? 1/0 : $6):($3 != i ? 1/0 : $9) with table
    unset table
}
reset session
EOF
echo "Sorting data";
for FILE in point-*
    do
        echo "Sorting $FILE"
        sort -k4 -n $FILE -o $FILE
    done
```

Comment: What does *"i tried to use it but anything works"* mean, exactly? Are `$3` ... `$9` intended to be column values accessed from within gnuplot, or positional parameters passed to the script?

Comment: `gnuplot` doesn't support your `do for [i=0:3] { ...}` construction. Read `man gnuplot`.

Comment: @waltinator so `gnuplot -e 'do for [i=0:3] {print i}'` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your answer, look, yes you are right those values are the columns of file, you get access from within gnuplot, the file called test contains more than 30 columns. And the important columns are the 3569. Let say that I more than 50000 values in column 3, and those values are: around 1000 with value "0" around 1000 with with value with value "1" and so on. What I did with gnuplot was to split such file into separated files called 'point-'.i.'csv'. then I tried to sort them using bash.

Comment: However, I am totally open I do you suggest to use some other tool or even just bash to split the raw file. I use gnuplot for plotting but I discovered that also you can create those files

Comment: @waltinator thanks for your answer, in my case if I start gnuplot and I apply the loop everything works. I don't know with you doesn't work.

Comment: If you want `$3` etc. to be parsed as **gnuplot** variables, you need to protect the from expansion by the shell - either individually like `\$3` or by quoting the here-document's end marker like `gnuplot -p << 'EOF'`, `gnuplot -p << "EOF"` or `gnuplot -p << \EOF`